# How can I change a string only four times depending on some conditions?

Tags: ios, string, swift, min, difference

Rephrase: I have one string "1234" and four ints: dif1,dif2,dif3 and dif4. What I am trying to achieve is change the characters in the string with other characters depending on the code below:

```
    var string = "1234"  

    var dif1: Int = it1 - it5
    var dif2: Int = it2 - it6
    var dif3: Int = it3 - it7
    var dif4: Int = it4 - it8

    // Negative values are not allowed
    if dif1 < 0 {
        dif1 = -dif1;
    }
    if dif2 < 0 {
        dif2 = -dif2;
    }
    if dif3 < 0 {
        dif3 = -dif3;
    }
    if dif4 < 0 {
        dif4 = -dif4;
    }
    var change = 0
    var minimum = min(dif1,dif2,dif3,dif4)

    // The first change that can happen for first character
    if dif1 < 13 && dif1 == minimum {
        change = 1
        // change the first character in string with another one depending on case!
    }
    else if dif2 < 13 && dif2 == minimum {
        change = 1
        ...
    }
    else if dif3 < 13 && dif3 == minimum {
        change = 1
        ...
    }
    else if dif4 < 13 && dif4 == minimum {
        change = 1
        ...
    }

    // The second change
    if (dif1 + dif2) < 13 {
        // If we have one change replace the second character
        if (change == 1) {
        ...
        }
        // else replace the first and record this as one change
        change = 2;
    }
    else if ((dif2 + dif3) < 13) {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        change = 2;
    }
    else if ((dif3 + dif4) < 13) {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        change = 2;
    }
    else if ((dif1 + dif4) < 13) {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        change = 2;
    }

    // The third change
    if ((dif1 + dif2 + dif3) < 13) {
        // If we have the first change replace the second character
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        // If we also have the second change replace the third character
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        // Else replace the first character and record as one change
        change = 3;
    }
    else if ((dif2 + dif3 + dif4) < 13) {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        change = 3;
    }
    else if ((dif3 + dif4 + dif1) < 13) {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        change = 3;
    }
    else if ((dif4 + dif1 + dif2) < 13) {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        change = 3;
    }

    if dif1 < 13 && dif1 != minimum {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        else if (change == 3) {
        }
        change = 4;
        }
    else if dif2 < 13 && dif2 != minimum {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        else if (change == 3) {
        }
        change = 4;
        }
    else if dif3 < 13 && dif3 != minimum {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        else if (change == 3) {
        }
        change = 4;
        }
    else if dif4 < 13 && dif4 != minimum {
        if (change == 1) {
        }
        else if (change == 2) {
        }
        else if (change == 3) {
        }
        change = 4;
        }
```

So how can I modifiy the string only four times depending on the above code?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Your description doesn't make much sense. We cantle what you're trying to do, and your code doesn't make things any clearer. You're going to have to provide a clear description of what you're trying to do if you want help.

Comment: just use a counter for that -> every modification you make you can set a counter like this : counter++; if the counter is 3 then just break/return the operation

Comment: I hope this explains better!

Answer (score 0):

Strange, what you're trying to do here, but check below compare function with example for you needs.
In **Playground**:

```
var dif1: Float = 52
var dif2: Float = 41.24
var dif3: Float = 141.1
var dif4: Float = 14.124

let allValues = [dif1, dif2, dif3, dif4]
func isDifferent(num: Float, value: Float, values: [Float]?, minimalCompareValue: Bool = true) -> Bool {
    if num > value {
        if values != nil && !values!.isEmpty {
            var minValue = values![0]
            let counts = values!.count
            for value in 1..<counts {
                 minValue = min(minValue, values![value])
            }

            return (value != minValue) == minimalCompareValue
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

println(isDifferent(53, dif1, allValues)) // true
```